# If statement condition where element equals element

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am testing a web page that contains a table. You can click a "Create new" link to add records to the grid. Once "Create New" is clicked, a dialog appears with some text boxes, another grid and a Cancel and Save button. You can then click a link to add a record to the dialog's grid which makes another dialog appear with text boxes and a Cancel and Save button. At my test level class, I currently click on these buttons then wait for the dialog's to open or close. I need to formulate a generic method which encompasses both the click and the wait, for each and every button. So instead of 2 lines of code at my test level to click an element and wait for a window, I would have one line of code that handles that. Below is my dilemma:

I need to be able to apply an `If` condition where a passed parameter of `IWebElement` equals a certain `IWebElement`, but it does not allow me to do this. The `if` statement doesn't find a match for some reason, so code inside the `if` statement never gets reached. Am I missing something? If not, is there a workaround?

NOTE: Using `button.text == SaveOrganizationBtn.Text` is a workaround, but would fail in my specific case, because some of these buttons might not have been loaded into the HTML for a certain test (i.e. A form has not been invoked), so the `if` statement fails. It would never be able to grab the `Text` property because it cant find the element in the first place.

Example code:

```
ClickButton(SaveNetworkBtn);

public void ClickButton(IWebElement button)
{
    if (button == SaveOrganizationBtn)
    {
        SaveOrganizationBtn.Click();
        WaitForOrganizationFormToClose();
    }

    if (button == SaveNetworkBtn)
    {
        SaveNetworkBtn.Click();
        WaitForNetworkFormToClose();
    }
```

Comment: You should check equality between these attribute value instead in string..

Comment: I saw you posted an answer but it feels like there's probably a better way to do this. Can you post the HTML of the two buttons and describe the scenario a little more? Is there some reason you can't just detect which button is available and click it rather than comparing it to a button you passed in?

Comment: I updated the original post to include the details of the application. Yes there is a reason I cant do that, its because multiple buttons could be "available" all at same time. As a user, I want to be able to specify which button I am going to click from the ones that are available

Comment: OK. Please post the HTML of the different buttons that might be available. There may be a way to detect which ones are available and click the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, however awkward it might look. I will mark this as the answer if no one else provides a better solution.

```
ClickButton(SaveNetworkBtn);

public bool ClickButton(IWebElement button)
{

bool buttonClicked = false;

    if (Driver.FindElements(By.Id("SaveOrg-Button-ID")).Count > 1)
    {
            if (button == SaveOrganizationBtn)
            {
                SaveOrganizationBtn.Click();
                WaitForOrganizationFormToClose();
                buttonClicked = true;
                return buttonClicked;
            }
    }

    if (Driver.FindElements(By.Id("SaveNet-Button-ID")).Count > 1)
    {
            if (button == SaveNetworkBtn)
            {
                SaveNetworkBtn.Click();
                WaitForNetworkFormToClose();
                buttonClicked = true;
                return buttonClicked;
            }
    }

return buttonClicked;
}
```

Comment: Small optimization: you can remove the `buttonClicked` variable. You can just `return true;` inside the `if`s and `return false;` at the bottom of the function.

Comment: Are you really meaning to check for `.Count > 1` instead of `.Count > 0`?

Comment: No. All I want to do is continue the conditional statement if that element By.ID is found

Comment: OK. Then you would want `.Count > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Equals()` method for your scenario. `==` will not work for this. you need to check it as `if(button.Equals(SaveOrganizationBtn))`. The result for this will be `true`, if it is the same object else it will return false.

I hope, it will help you.

Comment: alternatively you can use `button.GetType() == typeof(ClassBtn)`

Comment: This does not work. "The type or namespace SaveOrganizationBtn could not be found". Even if it did work, the If statements wont be distinguing between each IWebElement, it is only checking it's Type, and they are all of the same Type

Comment: I guess `SaveOrganizationBtn` is the `Id` of the button. I was thinking that It is a class. In that case, This answer will not work at all, you can try the `Equals` method for checking it both are the same object. I will edit the answer soon. Thanks

Comment: This did not work. It gave me the "no such element" exception for the first If statement that was checking a button that had not been loaded in the HTML. See "NOTE" in my original post for more info of how some buttons wont be in the HTML in certain tests. I created a round about way to accomplish what I want. I am posting that now

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your scenario but it seems like something like this might work... you will have to decide. Instead of passing in `button`, just check if the button exists on the page, if it does... click it.

```
ClickButton();

public bool ClickButton()
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> saveOrg = Driver.FindElements(By.Id("SaveOrg-Button-ID"));
    if (saveOrg.Any())
    {
        saveOrg.ElementAt(0).Click();
        WaitForOrganizationFormToClose();
        return true;
    }

    IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> saveNet = Driver.FindElements(By.Id("SaveNet-Button-ID"));
    if (saveNet.Any())
    {
        saveNet.ElementAt(0).Click();
        WaitForNetworkFormToClose();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

NOTE: `.Any()` works the same as `.Count > 0`, I found it a while back and like it a little better but it's a personal preference.

Comment: Clicking any available button is not my intention, so this will not work. I want to specify which button I am going to click. There could be multiple buttons available at the same time. i.e. A 'Cancel' and a 'Save' button

Comment: Are the Cancel and Save buttons going to have the same ID? This code isn't clicking any available button... it's clicking one of two buttons with specific IDs. More info on the relevant HTML would greatly help with finding a solution here.

Comment: Im sorry, I meant to say I dont want it to click "every button that is available in the html at the time". That is what your code above looks to be doing. If it finds that button by ID, then it clicks it. So if both the SaveNet and SaveOrg buttons are available, it is going to click them both. If you check out my posted solution, that is why I have a nested If statement, to specify which one to click